# Angular5 How to use Http Observable

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-services, angular-http, angular2-observables

I have a problem with HTTP requests on Angular5. 
I have two components ("**LoginComponent**", "**WellcomeComponent**") and one service ("**AuthService**").

I am using auth servise to handle HTTP requests , and also this service is a bridge between two components.

I can do get and post requests from service , but can't use results properly, because of Observable things. I am not an experienced Angular developer so can't find a solution.

So now , I am explaining step by step. I will write all my code here, and all steps are signed by **..Step_** text in code, so you can follow all steps by this sign.

---

> LoginComponent

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../../auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html'
})
export class LoginComponent {

    loginUserData = {}

    constructor(
        private _auth: AuthService,
        public router:Router ){
            //SOMETHING
        }

    //CLICK FORM SUBMIT BUTTON
    public onSubmit(values:Object):void {

        //SET USER DATA WITH FORM VALUES
        console.log("LoginStep_1 - Hello")

        this._auth.getToken(this.loginUserData)
        // CHECK TOKEN

        // IF VERIFIED
            console.log('LoginStep_2 - Token Verified');

            this._auth.setUserData(this.loginUserData['username']);
            console.log('LoginStep_3 - SetUserData Finished');

            this.router.navigate(['/wellcome'])
            console.log("LoginStep_4 - Navigated");
    }

}
```

---

> AuthService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    private _tokenUrl = "http://localhost:8000/api/auth/token/";
    private getUserInfoUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/userInfo/?username="
    private userInfo : any;

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        private _router: Router
    ) { }

    getToken(user){
        console.log("getToken_Step1 - Hello");

        this.http.post<any>(this._tokenUrl, user)
        .subscribe(
            res => {

                //getToken_Step2 : SET TOKEN SOMEWHERE
                console.log("getToken_Step2 - Token : ", res.token);

            },
            err => console.log(err)
        );

        console.log("getToken_Step3 - Bye");
    }

    setUserData(userName){
        console.log("setUserData_Step1 - Hello");

        this.http.get<any>(this.getUserInfoUrl+userName)
        .subscribe(
            res=>{

                //setUserData_Step2 : SET USERINFO SOMEWHERE
                console.log("setUserData_Step2 - User Info : ", res);

            },
            err=>{
                console.log(err);
            }
        )

        console.log("setUserData_Step3 - Bye");
    }

    getUserData(){
        console.log("getUserData_Step1 - Hello");
        return this.userInfo;
    }

}
```

---

> WellcomeComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../../auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-wellcome',
  templateUrl: './wellcome.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./wellcome.component.scss'],
})
export class WellcomeComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private _auth: AuthService){ }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("Wellcome_Step1 - Hello");
        let userInfo = this._auth.getUserData();
        console.log("Wellcome_Step2 - Show User Info");
    }

}
```

---

If you look codes, there are a lot of **console.log("Step..**, I am explaining what I want to do by using them.

In a short way, I can say I want to see them at this order in console screen :

1. **LoginStep_1** - Hello : *This step will work by clicking a submit button on a form*
2. **getToken_Step1** - Hello : *Go to auth service*
3. **getToken_Step2** - Token : *Get token from an API and write it localStorage*
4. **getToken_Step3** - Bye
5. **LoginStep_2** - Token Verified : *then come back and verify this token.*
6. **setUserData_Step1** - Hello
7. **setUserData_Step2** - User Info : *Get user info from an API and write it localStorage*
8. **setUserData_Step3** - Bye
9. **LoginStep_3** - SetUserData Finished : *I got token, verified it , got user info and wrote it. So I can go navigate now.*
10. **Wellcome_Step1** - Hello : *Navigated from Login*
11. **getUserData_Step1** - Hello : *get all info that written by LoginComponent*
12. **Wellcome_Step2** - Show User Info : *Do what You want with user info*

These steps are what I want to see on console log screen but, I can't see them with right order. My console output is very different from my expect. Because I don't know how to use angular 5 observable , so can't handle returned value from API.

My console output something like that :

> 1. LoginStep_1- Hello
> 2. LoginStep_3 - SetUserData Finished
> 3. getToken_Step1 - Hello
> 4. getToken_Step2 - Token

...
Here, why  this order ? How can I correct it ?

---

So now , How can I do this ? I want to take token and user info by LoginComponent and use them from WellCome component.

As I said, I am not an experienced coder, so maybe solution is very simple but couldn't find.

Thank you for your helps.

Comment: Because logging is **asynchronous** in nature, your `AuthService` should be implemented with such in mind. Specifically, your `getUserData` should return an **`Observable`**.

Answer (score 0):

Because your requests to backend is asynchronous, it will take time to execute. Therefore, Angular will move on to other tasks: `console.log('LoginStep_2 - Token Verified');` and `console.log('LoginStep_3 - SetUserData Finished');`  before the `getToken()` and `setUserData()` finished.

You can move subscribe to component

In your AuthService

```
    getToken(user){
        console.log("getToken_Step1 - Hello");

        return this.http.post<any>(this._tokenUrl, user)
        // subscribe moves to component
    }
```

In your component

```
this._auth.getToken(this.loginUserData)
  .subscribe(
    res => {

      //getToken_Step2 : SET TOKEN SOMEWHERE
      console.log("getToken_Step2 - Token : ", res.token);
    },
    err => console.log(err)
  )
```

Comment: Above breakdown of web service call and subscribe worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you should implement your function call to return either `promise` or `observable` (aka async). The `AuthService` is something like this (adapted from your question):

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

import {Observable, of} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  // private _tokenUrl = "http://localhost:8000/api/auth/token/";

  // This is just a mock URL that returns a response (200 OK)
  private _tokenUrl =
      "https://bikewise.org:443/api/v2/incidents?page=1&proximity_square=100";
  // private getUserInfoUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/userInfo/?username=";
  private userInfo: any;

  // can improve with getter/setter instead of exposing directly
  private isLoggedIn: boolean = false;

  isLoggedInObservable: Observable<boolean>;

  getToken(user): Promise<any> {
    console.log("getToken_Step1 - Hello");

    return new Promise(resolve => {

      // this.http.post<any>(this._tokenUrl, user)
      // fake request to make sure always get a response
      this.http.get<any>(this._tokenUrl)
          .subscribe(
              res => {

                // getToken_Step2 : SET TOKEN SOMEWHERE
                console.log("getToken_Step2 - Token : ", "token_1234");

                console.log("getToken_Step3 - Bye");
                // resolve(res.token);
                resolve("token1234");

              },
              err => {
                console.log(err);

                throw new Error('Unauthorized...');

              });
    })
  }

  setUserData(userName) {
    console.log("setUserData_Step1 - Hello");

    // If this is a real request, make sure to implement a promise/observable
    // return
    // this.http.get<any>(this.getUserInfoUrl + userName)

    // setUserData_Step2 : SET USERINFO SOMEWHERE
    console.log("setUserData_Step2 - User Info : ");

    console.log("setUserData_Step3 - Bye");
    this.isLoggedIn = true;
    this.isLoggedInObservable = of(true);
  }

  getUserData() {
    console.log("getUserData_Step1 - Hello");
    return this.userInfo;
  }

  logOut() {
    this.isLoggedInObservable = of(false);
    this.isLoggedIn = false;
  }

  isLogged(): boolean { return this.isLoggedIn; }
}
```

You also need to setup a `AuthGuard` for your routing to track whether user is logged in or not.

Here is a working example [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sg-simple-login-system). **Open console to track status**

Furthermore, you can always cache your user login status in browser `localStorage` to get better user experience. Again, this is adapted from your code. There are many things can be improved from your code. Let me know if you have further questions.